# Summer Cleanup Project #1: Duplicate Review

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

As The Workplace grows and looks to leave Beta, I think there are a few things cleanup duties that we should start doing to make the site tidier. Rather than create giant laundry lists which have less than stellar motivational powers, I am going to toss in what I'm doing and why I'm doing it, and the community can act (or not) as preferred.

Since this is still a (relatively) small site, cleanup is easy, and we can improve the quality of the site to make it a better resource for future users.

## Project #1: Duplicate Review

The following five questions are [duplicates with answers that have over 500 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A%3E%3D1+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Atrue+duplicate+views%3A%3E%3D500):

1. [How can you evaluate your market value?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/550/how-can-you-evaluate-your-market-value)
2. [How can I delay job offer acceptance?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/5854/how-can-i-delay-job-offer-acceptance)
3. [Optimal office size: cubicles versus small rooms versus open plan?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/592/optimal-office-size-cubicles-versus-small-rooms-versus-open-plan)
4. [How long can I wait to respond to a job offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/395/how-long-can-i-wait-to-respond-to-a-job-offer)
5. [When should someone accept more responsibilities without more money?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/when-should-someone-accept-more-responsibilities-without-more-money)

Since these are relatively high-view closed questions, I want to make sure of the following:

1. The question is actually a duplicate
2. The question is adequately answered
3. The original question contains all the information in the duplicate

Here is the pseudo-workflow I am using:

[image: Duplicate Cleanup Workflow]

For the 5 questions listed above, here is the action I have taken:

1. Added [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for/13463#13463) to the original
2. Added [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13464/7945)
3. Added [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13465/7945)
4. No action (accidentally voted to reopen)
5. Voted to [reopen](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/when-should-someone-accept-more-responsibilities-without-more-money#)

Next steps:

- There are [13 questions with 200-500 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A%3E%3D1+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Atrue+duplicate+views%3A200-500)
- Questions with "no action" may be candidates for deletion

If my approach can use refinement, or if someone can suggest a better way to go about this sort of stuff, please feel free to let me know. I plan to do similar things with high-view/high-score closed questions to determine:

1. Should they be reopened
2. Should they be edited and reopened
3. Should they be closed but left for future generations
4. Should they be deleted

I will start a separate meta entry when I start tackling that.

Comment: How do we know that the Workplace SE is looking to leave Beta?

Comment: If you're going to vote reopen, then vote to reopen. We'll see these candidates in the moderator tools. Why do you need to announce this?

Comment: @MichaelGrubey as far as I can tell, currently Workplace is about 2/3 on the road out of Beta (I think we'll graduate [at about 3K questions](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1884/when-will-the-workplace-graduate#comment2742_1884 "discussed in more details here"))

Comment: @JimG. I share this for two reasons. First of all because I bumped 3 questions by adding CW answers and that doesn't show up on moderator tools/doesn't give any justification on why I did it. Secondly because I think the community can get involved to help tidy things up, and sharing one way to do that can't hurt. Feel free to add close votes and downvote, but really, is what I'm doing a bad thing for the workplace?

Comment: No, it's not "bad"; but it just seems like wasted motion. // This post reminds me of Mark Trapp's summer cleanup posts. Of course, that guy was a fanatic. He would routinely close and edit posts between 2AM and 4AM local time! Unfortunately, after doing that for several months, he got burned out, resigned as moderator, and then asked SO to delete his profile! YMMV.

Comment: This is great! Getting more people in the community involved in reviewing questions is one of the reasons Workplace Meta exists.